# Check if some property is satisfied for all an element for all list elements

Tags: python, recursion

Given is list of binary strings of length n, some of which are codewords.

Inside main routine I want to add an element to a list of codewords if some conditions are met. The relevant part of the algorithm can be written as: starting with a list just one codeword add element to this list (from the list of all possible strings), if it has distance atleast d from the first codeword, then in order to add the next one we have to find first such string in the original list, which distance to both already added codewords is again atleast d. The same goes for fourth element - it's distance to the already found codewords should be atleast d. And so on...

Using recursion, I wrote following code, which ends with "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

What am I doing wrong? (I'm a python novice)

```
def helper(n,d,strings,codes,lastIndex):
    for i in range(lastIndex,n):
        distanceCheckSatisfied = True
        for j in range(len(codes)):
            if ( not(hammingDistance(codes[j],strings[i]) >= d) or not(distanceCheckSatisfied) ):
                distanceCheckSatisfied = False
            if (distanceCheckSatisfied):
                codes.append(strings[i])
                helper(n,d,strings,codes,i)
                break;
                break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second `break` will never be reached -- the Python `break` statement immediately breaks out of the innermost `for` or `while` loop. Which means that your *outer* `for` loop is still running.

Fixing that should rid yourself of a significant amount of recursive calls.

On a semi-related, style-guide topic:

- You shouldn't use semicolons in Python.
- Parentheses around conditions for `if` statements are unnecessary, and should be avoided unless you're using them to spread your condition across multiple lines.
- `not` is an operator, not a function -- use `not x`, instead of `not(x)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input (and code styling)... However, even removing the second break doesn't seem to be working (it is why I added it afterall)

Comment: Of course removing the second `break` didn't change anything -- it was never executed in the first place. It looks like you want to break out of the topmost for loop, which is equivalent to breaking out of the function. Replace your two `break` by a `return` statement.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work either.. What works for first function call is the following code:


 for i in range(n):
  if (hammingDistance(codes[0],strings[i])>=d):
   codes.append(strings[i])
   break